# Change a cell to a colour when a tick box is checked in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, data-validation

I have a cell with a checkbox. I want another cell which contains a date to go green when the tick box is checked. I presume this is done in conditional formatting but I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a cell with a check box. I want another cell which contains a
>   date to go green when the tick box is checked.

You go to `Format`, `Conditional Formatting` and use the `Custom formula`:

```
=COUNTIF($D3, "=TRUE")
```

[image]

> **EXTRA**:

On the other hand, if you want **the whole range/column to be highlighted** use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3, "=TRUE")
```

***Pay attention to the second `$` sign***.

[image]

Comment: @ChristopherGrant I am happy it worked out for you. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if an answer addressed your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote))

Answer (score 0):

- if you have a scenario like shown on the image all you need is custom formula **`=B1=TRUE`** applied to range **A1:A**

  [image: 0]